# Why does the code keep choosing the else option

Tags: cs50

so i'm in quite a bind with the ceaser problem set. I'm trying to confirm if the second command line argument is a number using the if-else statement below and the code keeps on choosing the 'else' option. I've converted the string argument with the 'atoi' function sooo help pls lol[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMkFa.png)

Comment: You should post your code as text, using the code tags.  Otherwise people can't copy-paste from it or try to run it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Microsoft C++ Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args):

> By convention, `argv[0]` is the command with which the program is
> invoked. `argv[1]` is the first command-line argument. The last
> argument from the command line is `argv[argc - 1]`, and `argv[argc]`
> is always NULL.

The second command line argument would be `argv[2]` and your `argc` should equal 3.